# How to build an extension to save values of HTML form to spreadsheet using app script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-apps-script

I am trying to build an extension to save values of HTML form to a spreadsheet using google app script.

I am able to save when I publish as a web app through app script.
But when I try the same from an extension that doesn't work.

How the app script URL should be called in order to post the values to the spreadsheet from an extension when we submit the form?

HTML:

```
<form name="input">
    <!-- fieldset draws a border around all the input elements -->
    <fieldset>
        <!-- There are form attributes, like type, name, id -->
        <input type="text" value="Manufacturer"
            class="ss-q-short" id="id_Maker" dir="auto" aria-required="true"
            title=""> <br>
        <br>

        <br> <input type="button" value="Save Input"
            onclick="WriteInput()"> <input type="reset" value="Reset">

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

JS FILE:

```
<script>
     function WriteInput() {
     alert("hello");
        var d=new Date();
        var daMonth = d.getMonth() + 1;
        var ToInputStrng = (daMonth + "/" + d.getDate() + "/" + d.getFullYear()  + " " + d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds());
         alert(ToInputStrng);
        var strngTwo = document.getElementById('id_Maker').value;

        alert(strngTwo);

        google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure)
           .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
           .AddToSheet(ToInputStrng, strngTwo);
    }
</script>
```

app script:

```
function doGet(){
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('OfferedInput')
            .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}

function AddToSheet(InputData, InputTwo){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Put the spreadsheet ID here");
    return sheet.appendRow([InputData, InputTwo]);
}
```

Comment: The thing you named `JS FILE` isn't actually a *file* but an embedded/inlined js-script which doesn't work in modern Chrome extensions. It should be a separate `.js` file loaded via `<script src="..."></script>` in the html.

Answer (score 0):

Put a "scriptlet" into your "OfferedInput" HTML file.  The "scriptlet" is `<?!= include("JS"); ?>`.  Make sure to use `<!DOCTYPE html><html>` and `<body>` tags in your HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <?!= include("JS"); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form name="input">
    <!-- fieldset draws a border around all the input elements -->
    <fieldset>
        <!-- There are form attributes, like type, name, id -->
        <input type="text" value="Manufacturer"
            class="ss-q-short" id="id_Maker" dir="auto" aria-required="true"
            title="">
        <br>
        <br>
        <br> 

        <input type="button" value="Save Input" onclick="WriteInput()"> 
        <input type="reset" value="Reset">

    </fieldset>
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

The scriplet causes the HTML file to be a "template".  Now you must use the `createTemplateFromFile()` method in the `doGet()`.  And you need an `include()` function.

```
function doGet() {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('OfferedInput');

  // Build and return HTML in IFRAME sandbox mode.
  return template.evaluate()
      .setTitle('Web App Window Title')
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
};

function include(filename) {
  //Logger.log('filename: ' + filename)
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
};
```

Set the sandbox mode to IFRAME, NATIVE is considered deprecated.

Comment: the problem is deeper. he is trying to use the apps script htmlService implementation directly as a chrome extension, which would never work.

Comment: Thank you all for you efforts in helping me on this. I think i have not put my question correctly.need help how to call the the google app script web app url : https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyo8e9kfJll_ywRp99ncgERxAw0Jd7dmWoroc7kPfX7WdO_tKKM/exec on clicking the chrome extension button.